# Crystal: Display Nth record based off Parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Real quick -- I want to display the last detail record that occurs BEFORE a specific parameter date that I choose.  I was trying to write something like this:

`recordnumber = count(({assign.date} > {?Date}) - 1)`

or

`recordnumber = onlastrecord - count({assign.date} > {?Date}) - 1`

When I click 'check' it highlights assign.date and states "A field is required here"

Whenever I google this I see REALLY COMPLICATED answers to something that I feel should be really simple; and I just don't know enough about Crystal to deploy one of those complicated answers.

Comment: Suppress all other detail records?  How is the report sorted?

Comment: I have it sorted by Client #. The report currently displays stuff like:

Client # ||| Begin Date ||| Assigned Employee
5 ||| 1/1/2013 ||| Marc 
5 ||| 2/16/2013 ||| Sandy
5 ||| 6/1/2013 ||| Josh

I did some programming to chop off assignments AFTER my {?Date} parameter, but I can't chop off 'all but the most recent' employee assignments.  The goal of this was to be able to say (using a parameter) “Who was serving our clients on 3/1/2013” and get the correct answer for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

- Create a new formula field, name it LastDate_Details and add the following code inside the Formula editor.

  ```
  WhilePrintingRecords;

  Shared DateVar LastDate;

  if CDate({assign.date}) < CDate({?Date}) then
      LastDate:= CDate({assign.date})
  ```
- Drag and drop the formula field somewhere on the details section and suppress it by right clicking on the field -> Format Object -> Common Tab -> and checking the suppress CheckBox.
- Create another formula called LastDate_Footer and add the following code.

  ```
  Shared DateVar LastDate;
  ```
- Drag and drop the new formula field on the footer section.

**EDIT**

For more information about variable scope in Crystal Reports check [**this**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crconvariablescopecrystalsyntax.htm).

Comment: You don't need to use a `Shared` variable unless you are passing values to/from a subreport.  Use a `Global` instead.

Comment: You're right. I usually declare them as Shared based on my own programming conventions :). Thanks for the notice.

Comment: I tried to make the new formula field and when I click 'check for errors' it highlights {assign.date} states "A Date-Time is required here"  ?